# What happens to the objects created inside a using statement?

Tags: c#, using-statement

I have been trying to search for this and could not find an answer, May be I was not looking at the right places so please bear with me...

**Question:**

I know that a `using` statement calls the dispose method of the object, for example:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    // some work
} 
// dispose method for this connection object will be called must.
```

But what happens to the objects created inside this `using` statement?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    // some work
}
```

Will the dispose method of command object be also called? Or should I do this instead:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        //some work
    }
    // some work
}
```

Which is the best practice and which one will be more efficient ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the dispose method of command object be also called?

No

> Or should I do this instead:

Yes

> Which is the best practice and which one will be more efficient ?

The one that works - the last one. Note you can avoid "heading right" on the page:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // some work
}
```

I'm too lazy to use ADO.NET directly; another option is to get a tool to handle everything except the connection (example shown is "dapper", but other tools exist):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(someSql, new { foo, bar }).ToList();
                    // where @foo and @bar are parameters in the sql
}
```

then you don't need to worry about the command, data-reader, parameters, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response... You said another option is to get a tool? can you kindly tell me which tool except dapper will be best or which one you use??

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi "best" is subjective and needs an "at what?". Since I'm the primary author of "dapper", it's a fair bet that I mainly use: "dapper".

Comment: Actually I have not used dapper before and I do not know how to... I think I will go read stuff about it and start using it :)

Comment: One more question, objects created inside a scope are not accessible outside the scope and GC itself marks them to be disposable and then dispose them off later, so that memory will eventually be freed? Right?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi GC has nothing to do with disposable whatsoever; completely separate concepts and concerns. GC never ever disposes anything. It sometimes *finalizes* things, but that is very different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should use the second. also you can shorten that statement to:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    //some work
}
// some work
```

If you don't wrap your disposable object with a `using` statement the Dispose method will not be called.In your case only the `connection` will be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that a using statement calls the dispose method of the object, for example:

If that object implements the `IDisposable` interface. Otherwise, you can't even use an object in a `using` statement.

You should use a `using` statement for each object you want to dispose of after some operations. So you should use the last example you provided yourself (with the two using statements).